# Clear a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: c#

I have a private field in a class which is a dictionary of dictionaries.

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, int>> 
myDict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, int>>();
```

What's the best practice regarding clearing `myDict`? Do I have to loop on all the values and call *Clear* on each or is it enough if I just called *Clear* on `myDict`??
I'm looking for the best performance too.

Comment: it depends on your scenario

Comment: Provided that you just want to wipe all records from both dictionaries and work with empty dictionary I'd probably just create a new instance : `myList = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, int>>();`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you call `Clear()`, it will clear the master dictionary. If there are no references any more to the inner dictionaries, the garbage collector will clean them up, so there is no need to call `Clear()` on them. If they are still being referenced, you have to unreference those first on you might end up with an invalid state.

Comment: I'm not calling it a list :). I just changed the name for the sake of the question.

Comment: Then don't call it a list in your question.

Comment: Probably most efficient is to use `myList = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, int>>(myList.Count);`.

Comment: Depends, if you intend to fill it again, you have to start over resizing the thing. If you keep the instance, it might keep the memory allocated too @TimSchmelter

Comment: @PatrickHofman: i have used the constructor that takes the capacity

Comment: But wouldn't it be pointless to reallocate space you already have allocated?

Comment: After Clear() you can call GC.Collect() to force garbage collection if you need to free up memory. Collect has various arguments that you can set, please check MSDN for that.

Answer (score 0):

Just called Clear on myList this is the best way.

In you code I can see myList  is readonly, check if it can be cleared or not.

Comment: `readonly` means you can't change the instance linked, not the contents. It is not a `const`.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep (pointer-)copies of the 2nd level dictionaries somewhere it is saver to clear all of them. If you only access them directly trough the "mother" dictionary or temporary variables inside of a method they are collected by the garbage collector sooner or later so you don't have to `Clear` them seperately.